# Web Firebase var changes from Timestamp type to object type after return through Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to return a firebase Timestamp object through cloud functions. After I return it to the frontend it no longer has the firebase Timestamp type.
The error I get is: :

```
timestamp.toMillis is not a function
```

( toMillis is a method specific to firebase Timestamp, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)

If I get the data without using cloud functions , straight from the frontend , the type remains.

The code from backend returning:

```
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    messageArray.push({
      ...
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
      ...
    });
  });
  return messageArray;
```

Frontend:

```
var getMessages = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getMessages');
  getMessages({
    data: displayName,
    chatType: chatType
  }).then(function (result) {
    console.log("loading messages");
    result.data.forEach(message => {
      console.log(typeof message.timestamp);
      console.log(message.timestamp);
      var timestamp = message.timestamp;
      var millis = timestamp.toMillis();
    });
```

If I were to do get my data without cloud functions like this , it works:

```
 query.onSnapshot(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        deleteMessage(change.doc.id);
      } else {
        var message = change.doc.data();
        console.log(message.timestamp);
        console.log(typeof  message.timestamp);
        var timestamp = message.timestamp;
        var millis = timestamp.toMillis();
      }
    });
  });
```

Why does the type change and how can I convert it into a firebase Timestamp ?

Cloud functions version log:
[image]

Only frontend version log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable type Cloud Functions serialize the response as plain JSON.  No object types are retained.  When you have a Timestamp object in the response, the functiosn SDK will simply call `toJSON` on it to get a JSON object for serialization.  Again, it will completely lose its type information, and contain **only** properties for its seconds and nanosecond components when it reaches the client app.  That's what your console log is actually showing - a plain JavaScript object with two properties.

If you want to convert that JSON object into a Timestamp on the client side, you will need to read the seconds and nanoseconds properties out of the deserialized object and pass them to the [Timestamp constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor).